# mysqldump have issue in cPanel cron job

Tags: linux, mysql, cpanel

To create auto backup of database, I am using this command in cPanel cron job

```
mysqldump --opt -Q -u {mysql_user_name} --password='{password}' {database} | gzip > /home/[account_name]/db_backup/db_backup$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").sql.gz
```

When i try to run this command via SSH/putty its working properly , but when using at cPanel cron (Server OS is CENTOS 7.6 kvm ) I am getting this error

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: do you have special characters in your password, by any chance?

Comment: @Bart Yes. like this >  +FDj[5%*7

Comment: Think `%` would be problematic, you need to escape it. % has a special meaning to cron. You must escape it when you put it directly in your crontab -- but only your crontab, not elsewhere. in the cron job, do you use the bare command or a script that contains the command? If bare command, try putting it inside a shell script instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have special character in your MySQL password, you need to escape it if you want to use bare command in cron job, since `%` has a special meaning to cron.

I'd advise using a script instead, e.g. a simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump --opt -Q -u'{mysql_user_name}' --password='{password}' {database} | gzip > /home/[account_name]/db_backup/db_backup$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").sql.gz
```

You could go a step further, and move the credentials to variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_USER="{mysql_user_name}"
MY_PWD="{password}"

mysqldump --opt -Q -u"$MY_USER" --password="$MY_PWD" {database} | gzip > /home/[account_name]/db_backup/db_backup$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").sql.gz
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Hi , i just tried using simple password and getting same error again. 2nd i am using mysqldump command directly in cPanel cron setting not using bash file.

Comment: see here >  https://prnt.sc/o7ddhe

Comment: so the `{mysql_user_name}`, `{password}`, `{database}` are used just like in the above pasted command? Curly brackets, so `{` and `}` are also special for cron and you cannot use them there.

Comment: not using Curly brackets in command .. just placeholder for question

Comment: command is working properly via ssh but not at cPanel cron job

Comment: why can't you wrap it in a script file and try like that? there's also `$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N")` bit, you need to escape `%` sign, as I said.